# Create dynamic text boxes then write to text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, csv

So there must be an easier way to create this. I have a form with the following HTML:

```
      <p>Names</p>
        <ul class="container1"  style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li><input type="text" size="10"  name="Name" /></li>
        </ul>
       <input type="button" class="add_form_field" value="+">
```

I then added some JS to create new text boxes if a user needs to add more names:
Taken from: http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2017/02/dynamically-generate-form-fields-using.html

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10;
var wrapper         = $(".container1");
var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");

var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="Name"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
    else
     {
         alert('You Reached the limits')
          }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");
  
    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="Name"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
  else
  {
  alert('You Reached the limits')
  }
    });
  
    $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});


    function check() {
      var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("formElem");
      if (document.getElementById("ckbox").checked) {            
        for (var e = 0; e < temp.length; e++) { // For each element
          var elt = temp[e];
          elt.required = false;
        }
      } else {
        for (var e = 0; e < temp.length; e++) { // For each element
          var elt = temp[e];
          elt.required = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Names</p>
    <ul class="container1"  style="list-style-type:none;">
     <li><input type="text" size="10"  name="Name" /></li>
  </ul>
         
 <input type="button" class="add_form_field" value="+">
```

I then need to write those appended values to a .CSV file using PHP and here is where I am having the issue:

```
  <?php
        // Receive form Post data and Saving it in variables
           header('Location: thanks.html'); 
          $Name = "";

          $Name = @$_POST ['Name'];

        // Write the name of text file where data will be store
          $filename = "file.csv";

        // Merge all the variables with text in a single variable. 
            $f_data= '
            Names for people: '.$Name.'                  ';

             $file = fopen($filename, "r+");
             fwrite($file,$f_data);
             fclose($file);
?>
```

What happens is that the last appended text box gets written into the csv file.Is there a way to pass these created text boxes so they can write to a the file? Really similar question: [Pass dynamic text input to PHP in order to write to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809521/pass-dynamic-text-input-to-php-in-order-to-write-to-text-file)

But I'm not sure if this can be done with text boxes.

Comment: Check your developer console and see if there's anything from using error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php set to catch and display. If everything works but fails to write to the file, it could be a permissions issue and/or you're outputting before header.

Comment: You should also remove the `@` in `@$_POST` since it's an error suppressor.

Comment: I'm responding to both ishegg  and Fred-ii-. So it was working, I was just not adding my id's correctly in the JS. I actually ended up using a much simpler code that dynamically creates text boxes.  Thank for for the help ishegg and Fred-ii-!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every input you add has the name “name”, so PHP can only access the last one (which overwrote the others). To get around this, you can add an index to the input name or make an array of them. This can be achieved like so:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]"...>
```

So now, on the PHP script you can iterate over that array to get all the inputs, or implode all the elements into a variable:

```
<?php
$names = implode(", ", $_POST["name"]); // all the names, comma-separated 
?>
```

Now you can use $names inside $f_data to see all the inputted fields.

(Thanks Fred-ii for the heads up about the quotes)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense to use an array here. However, there is not a way for that loop to be implemented in $f_data so I can actually see the inputted values, right?

Comment: If I understand correctly: concatenate all the values into a variable instead of echoing like in my example. I’ll update the post.

Comment: `“ ”` all of those need to be changed to `"` - they will throw a parse error and produce invalid/unusable HTML.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, apparently the iPad Pro keyboard “auto corrects” the quotes.

Comment: welcome. I take it that you're unable to change them?

Comment: I noticed that as well and I did change them to " ". However, when I do implode the array it's still not writing into my text file. I've been trying to figure out what I could be doing wrong as I am still learning lots about PHP. Would I have to replace   $Name = @$_POST ['Name']; with $names = implode(“, “, $_POST[“name”]);?

Comment: @Gabriel What is it writing? Can you paste the current output?

Comment: It 's currently not outputting the values: Names for people: (It's blank here) I' leaving  $Name = @$_POST ['Name']; and putting $names = implode(", ", $_POST["name"]); right below it.

Comment: Well, did you change the $Name variable in $f_data to $names? Furthermore, make sure you keep the casing consistent (variable names are case-sensitive). So, if you’re getting $_POST[“name”], make sure the name in the input is lowercase. If it’s capitalized, use $_POST[“Name”];